# Как сделать сектора в пончике со скругленными углами?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, диаграммы, chart.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?
Мне нужен мульти-сектор в пончике с закругленными концами и добавить тень самому пончику.

Хочу использовать `chart.js`, но можно и другие варианты без `jquery`.

Comment: все ответы достойные - выберите какой то лучшим !

Answer (score 16):

Есть вариант сделать с помощью SVG. На последней секции(#part4) в качестве примера заливка градиентом.

UPD: Добавил еще [вариант без CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825021/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/825050#answer-825203)

```css
.circle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 }
#part1 {
  stroke: #172bc3;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
#part2 {
  stroke: #f21d92;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
}
#part3 {
  stroke: #9631eb;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: rotate(-160deg);
}
#part4 {
  stroke: url(#gradient);
  z-index: 4;
  transform: rotate(-250deg);
}
#shadow {
  stroke: white;
  z-index:1;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="part1" class="circle" viewBox="256 346 100 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="line" d="M268.5,395.9c0-20.7,16.8-37.4,37.4-37.4"/>
  </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#line"/>
</svg>
<svg id="part2" class="circle" viewBox="256 346 100 100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <use xlink:href="#line"/>
</svg>
<svg id="part3" class="circle" viewBox="256 346 100 100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#line"/>
</svg>
<svg id="part4" class="circle" viewBox="256 346 100 100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00bc9b" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5eaefd" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#line"/>
</svg>
<svg id="shadow" class="circle" viewBox="256 346 100 100">
 <defs>
    <filter id="blurMe" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="4" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="3" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<circle cx="306" cy="396" r="38" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Павел ты БОГ O.o

Comment: @Spectr, сейчас будет моё решение на одних кругах=)))

Comment: Обновил решение: убрал копи-паст одной и той же path, заменив их с помощью <use>.

Answer (score 14):

Решается вопрос с помощью `SVG`. Применил `circles`, вместо `paths`( почему бы и нет?:D ):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blurMe" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="5" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="3" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="100" filter="url(#blurMe)" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
  <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="#f21d92" stroke-width="20" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="350"/>
  <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="#9631eb" stroke-width="20" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="-150"/>
  <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="#172bc3" stroke-width="20" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="-330"/>
  <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="#5eaefd" stroke-width="20" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="-470"/>
  <circle cx="110" cy="10" r="10" fill="#5eaefd"/>
  <circle cx="120" cy="209.5" r="10" fill="#f21d92"/>
  <circle cx="210" cy="110" r="10" fill="#f21d92"/>
  <circle cx="11" cy="95" r="10" fill="#172bc3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: *Фильтры позаимствовал у Павла* (спасибо).

Comment: а мне в голову circles позже пришли :) жаль я голосовать пока не могу, плюсик позже поставлю, классное решение

Comment: @Pavel, такие вещи просто с `path` реализовать, это конечно не плохо(даже хорошо), но нужно знать альтернативные решения=)

Comment: естественно, но на сколько просто будет работать с анимацией этих кругов? как будет с градиентом?

Comment: @Pavel, с `gradient`'ами ещё куда ни крути, а вот с анимацией сомнительно, будут сложности со смещениями контура и т.д.(для неопытного конечно)

Comment: @Pavel, приглашаю в `SVG`-чат, будет интересно поговорить про само направление и не только=) ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat )

Answer (score 11):

Вариант SVG без CSS

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="200px" width="200px">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="line" viewBox="256 346 100 100">
      <path stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" d="M268.5,395.9c0-20.7,16.8-37.4,37.4-37.4"/>
    </symbol>
    <filter id="blurMe" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="4" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="3" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00bc9b" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5eaefd" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle fill="transparent" stroke="white" stoke-width="2" cx="50" cy="43" r="37" filter="url(#blurMe)"/>
  <use stroke="#f21d92" xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(-14, 73) rotate(-70)"/>
  <use stroke="#172bc3" xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(20, -20) rotate(20)"/>
  <use stroke="url(#gradient)" xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(113, 14) rotate(-250)"/>
  <use stroke="#9631eb" xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(79, 107) rotate(-160)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

Решение с Chart.js начиная от 2.1.0+

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
  afterUpdate: function (chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor !== undefined) {
      items=chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor;
      items.forEach(function(element) {
        var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[element];            
        arc.round = {
          x: (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2,
          y: (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2,
          radius: (chart.outerRadius + chart.innerRadius) / 2,
          thickness: (chart.outerRadius - chart.innerRadius) / 2 - 1,
          backgroundColor: arc._model.backgroundColor
        }
      });
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function (chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor !== undefined) {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      items=chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor;
      items.forEach(function(element) {
        var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[element];
        var startAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.startAngle;
        var endAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.endAngle;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = arc.round.backgroundColor; 
        ctx.beginPath();
        //получаются артефакты
        //ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(startAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(startAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI); 
        ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
      });
    }

  },
});

var settings = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [25, 25, 25,25],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#363edc",
        "#48d0f0",
        "#9a31eb",
        "#f11e94"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#363edc",
        "#48d0f0",
        "#9a31eb",
        "#f11e94"
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
      rotation: 10,
      cutoutPercentage: 80,
        legend: {
          display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
          enabled: false
      },
      elements: {
        arc: {
          roundedCornersFor: [0,1,2,3]
        }
      }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myTest").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, settings);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myTest"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

`D3.js` вариация, [похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962996/188366).

Обратите внимание на заморочку, что бы перекрытие было не как в макете дизайнера, а правильно, в одну сторону.

Похожие перекрытия в ответе господина `@Pavel` с решением на `Chart.js`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let overlap = 0.2, 
    duration = 1000,
    count = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
    data = Array(count).fill(0).map((d, i) => ({value: 1 + 5*Math.random()}));

let svg = d3.select('#donut g');
let pie = d3.pie().sort(null); // 
let arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(70).outerRadius(85);
let d = pie(data.map(d => d.value));
d.forEach(d => d.endAngle += overlap);

drawArcs("right");
drawArcs("left");

function drawArcs(className) {
  let right = className === "right";
  svg.selectAll("path." + className).data(d).enter()
     .append("path").classed(className, true)
     .attr("fill", (d, i) => `hsl(${i*77},75%,45%)`)
     .transition().duration(duration).attrTween('d', tween)
   
  function tween(d) {
    let center = (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2;
    let interpolator = d3.interpolate(center, right ? d.endAngle : d.startAngle)
    return t => {
        let v = interpolator(t);
        d.startAngle = right ? center - overlap*t : v;
        d.endAngle = right ? v : center + overlap*t;
        return arc.cornerRadius(10*t)(d);
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="donut" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"/> 
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/> 
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g style="filter:url(#dropshadow)"></g>
</svg>
```

---

UPD: по просьбам трудящихся добавил сделал вариант с анимацией заполнения в одну сторону.

```js
let overlap = 0.2, 
    duration = 1000,
    count = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
    data = Array(count).fill(0).map((d, i) => ({value: 1 + 5*Math.random()}));

let svg = d3.select('#donut g');
let pie = d3.pie().sort(null); // 
let arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(70).outerRadius(85);
let d = pie(data.map(d => d.value));
d.forEach(d => d.endAngle += overlap);

drawArcs("right");
drawArcs("left");

function drawArcs(className) {
  let right = className === "right";
  svg.selectAll("path." + className).data(d).enter()
     .append("path").classed(className, true)
     .attr("fill", (d, i) => `hsl(${i*77},75%,45%)`)
     .transition().duration(duration).attrTween('d', tween)
   
  function tween(d) {
    let center = d.startAngle;
    let interpolator = d3.interpolate(center, right ? d.endAngle : d.startAngle)
    return t => {
        let v = interpolator(t);
        d.startAngle = right ? center : v;
        d.endAngle = right ? v : center + overlap*t;
        return arc.cornerRadius(10*t)(d);
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="donut" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"/> 
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/> 
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g style="filter:url(#dropshadow)"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95956/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q-------).