# Как сделать круговую диаграмму, зависимую от чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Нужно, что бы диаграмма заполнялась в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов. Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPD: [версия со скругленными секторами может выглядеть вот так](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/PgYBEX)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собрал пример на `svg` + `d3.js`, для генерации `svg` путей в `d3` есть модуль [d3-shape](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape), в котором есть генераторы для фигур различных форм, в том числе [d3.pie()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#pie) и [d3.arc()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arc) из которых в свою очередь собран этот пример.

Все переходы посчитаны при помощи [d3.interpoalte()](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate) который любезно умеет интерполировать цвета, строки, объекты =)

**UPD: доделал начальную анимацию линий подписей**

> Более подробные комментарии в коде

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<span id="checkboxes">
  <label><input type="checkbox" val="111" checked></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" val="222"></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" val="333" checked></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" val="444"></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" val="555" checked></label>
</span>

<span id="donut"></span>

<script>
  let rawData = [...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input')].map(cb => 
     ({ value: +cb.getAttribute('val'), selected: cb.checked }));

  // базовый размер и время анимации
  let size = 175, time = 500; 
  
  // цветовая шкала 
  // (функция которая принимает на вход число и возвращает цвет, тут их 10)
  let colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  // чекбоксы
  d3.select('#checkboxes').selectAll('label').data(rawData)
    .style('background-color', (d, i) => colors(i))
    
  d3.select('#checkboxes').selectAll('input').data(rawData)  
    .on("change", function (d) { 
      update(d.selected = this.checked); 
    });

  // добавим svg
  let svg = d3.select('#donut').append("svg").attr("height", size)
              .attr("viewBox", `-${size} -${size/2} ${size*2} ${size}`);

  // инициализируем генератор данных для передачи в генератор arc()
  let pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.selected ? d.value : 0).sort(null);

  let pieData = pie(rawData);

  // инициализируем генератор дуг для секторов
  let arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(size/3.1-30).outerRadius(size/3.1);

  // инициализируем генератор дуг для подсчета линий подписей
  let arc2 = d3.arc().innerRadius(size/2.7).outerRadius(size/2.7);

  // инициализируем генератор дуг для подсчета центров текста подписей
  let arc3 = d3.arc().innerRadius(size/2.2).outerRadius(size/2.2);

  // инициализируем генератор линий
  let line = d3.line();

  // создаем выборку (групп) элементов и привязываем к ней данные
  let groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(rawData)
                  .enter().append("g").attr('opacity', (d,i) => pieData[i].value);

  // добавляем пути для секторов в группы, 
  // данные привязанные к группам тут нам достаются по наследству
  let sectors = groups.data(pieData).append("path").classed("sector", true)
                      .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors(i));

  // пути для линий подписей
  let titlesPaths = groups.data(pieData).append("path").classed("label", true);

  // тексты подписей
  let titlesTexts = groups.data(pieData).append("text")
                          .text((d,i) => rawData[i].value);

  // текст в центре 
  let totalText = svg.append('text').style('font-size', 22).attr('y', 2);

  // начальная анимация путей секторов                 
  sectors.transition().duration(time).attrTween('d', growSectorsPaths); 

  // начальная анимация путей для подписей
  titlesPaths.transition().duration(time).attr('opacity', 1)
             .attrTween('d', growTitlesPaths); 

  // начальная анимация текста подписей
  titlesTexts.transition().duration(time)
          .attrTween("x", tweenTitlesTextsX)
          .attrTween("y", tweenTitlesTextsY);
          
  // начальная анимация текста по центру
  totalText.datum(calcTotal()).transition().duration(time)
           .tween("text", interpolateTotal)

  function update() {
      let d = pie(rawData);

      // задаем анимацию перехода путям секторов 
      sectors.data(d).transition().duration(time)
          .attrTween("d", tweenSectorsPaths);

      groups.data(d).transition().duration(time)
          .attr('opacity', d => d.value ? 1 : 0)

      // задаем анимацию перехода путям для подписей
      titlesPaths.data(d).transition().duration(time)
          .attrTween("d", tweenTitlesPaths);

      // задаем анимацию перехода путям для подписей
      titlesTexts.data(d).transition().duration(time)
          .attrTween("x", tweenTitlesTextsX)
          .attrTween("y", tweenTitlesTextsY);
          
      // анимация текста по центру
      totalText.datum(calcTotal()).transition().duration(time)
           .tween("text", interpolateTotal) 
  }

  function growTitlesPaths(d) {
      let i = d3.interpolate(size/4, size/2.7);
      return t => {
        let r = i(t);
        arc2.innerRadius(r).outerRadius(r);
        return line([arc.centroid(this._current = d),arc2.centroid(d)]);
      }
  }

  function growSectorsPaths(d) {
     let c = (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2;
     let il = d3.interpolate(c, d.startAngle);
     let ir = d3.interpolate(c, d.endAngle)
     return t => {
       d.startAngle = il(t);
       d.endAngle = ir(t);
       return arc(this._current = d);
     }; 
  }

  function tweenSectorsPaths(d) {
    let i = lerp(this, d);
    return t => arc(i(t));
  }

  function tweenTitlesPaths(d) {
    let i = lerp(this, d);
    return t => line([arc.centroid(i(t)), arc2.centroid(i(t))]);
  }

  function tweenTitlesTextsX(d) {
    let i = lerp(this, d, '_currentX');
    return t => arc3.centroid(i(t))[0];
  }

  function tweenTitlesTextsY(d) {
    let i = lerp(this, d, '_currentY');
    return t => arc3.centroid(i(t))[1];
  }

  function interpolateTotal(d) {
    let i = lerp(this, d);
    return t => Math.round(i(t));
  }

  function lerp(el, d, key){
    key = key || '_current';
    return d3.interpolate(el[key] || 0, el[key] = d);
  }

  function calcTotal() {
    return rawData.map(d => d.selected ? d.value : 0).reduce((a,v) => a + v, 0)
  }

  function interpolateTotal(d) {
    let that = d3.select(this);
    let i = lerp(this, d);
    return t => that.text(Math.floor(i(t)))
  }
</script>

<style>
  label {
    display: block;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  path.label {
    stroke-width: 1.4;
    stroke: black;
  }
  text {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    dominant-baseline: middle;
    text-anchor: middle;  
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Супер............

Comment: @Air потом сделаю анимацию поадекватнее, тут надо подольше посидеть =)

Comment: Вот теперь я считаю что уже можно людям показать.

Comment: Оооох, огроменное спасибо, я сейчас немного занят другим проектом, но думаю сегодня внедрю и отмечу как решение, блин, реально спасибо!!!!

Comment: @AleksandrKrais как Вы догадались мне понравился Ваш вопрос))

Comment: @AleksandrKrais если Вы хотите понять как это реализовано Вам необходимо прочитать про d3 и выборки https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: Большущее спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: А я никак не могу поменять цвета заливки на кастомные?

Comment: Я просто не могу понять как мне это все возможно стилизовать под свои нужды:\

Comment: Мне нужно как-то добавить градиент вместо цветов для кусочков, как-то добавить блоки с текстами, белые круглешки в качестве конца отрезка, 
Могу ли я в svg положить html элемент? 
Т.е. я например положил бы html-блок с подписями, а по окончании рисования отрезка изменял бы его прозрачность на странице, что бы я мог там написать количество брендов вместе с количество товаров и положил бы туда название категории

Comment: то есть, что бы получить результат 1 в 1, мне надо посмотреть на что-то другое?

Comment: Что мне нужно посмотреть, что бы получилось доделать 1в1 с картинкой? вообще возможно ли?

Comment: Да, рисовал дизайнер

Comment: возможно ли попробовать codepen?

Comment: Давайте сделаем все закругления по часовой, думаю, что это ошибка дизайнера

Comment: Окей, я буду тогда держать руку на пульсе так сказать и даже не знаю как Вас благодарить...

Comment: Заменю этим вечернее чтиво:)

Comment: я как раз в ближайшем будущем планирую изучать 3d анимации и 3d web в целом, будет полезно

Comment: @AleksandrKrais https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/PgYBEX