# Как сверстать круговой график на svg

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation

Есть такой вот макет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы разноцветные дуги можно было выставит в зависимости от значений. 
Как сверстать такой график на svg?

То есть должен получиться вот такой вот график в итоге с значениями слева

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот `d3.js` версия, если угодно. Используем генератор примитивов `d3.arc()`

он на вход кушает объект-описание дуги, а на выходе дает готовый `<path>`

```js
let data = {
  innerRadius: 10,
  outerRadius: 20,
  startAngle: Math.PI/4,
  endAngle: Math.PI*3/2,
  cornerRadius: 201
}

let d = d3.arc().cornerRadius(22)(data)

d3.select('svg').append('path')
  .attr('d', d).attr('fill', '#0ad01f')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
  <svg viewBox="-30 -20 75 75" height="100vh"></svg>
<body>
```

---

Анимация диаграммы:

```js
let data = [
  [1, '#0578e9'], 
  [2, '#f278bb'], 
  [3, '#f9b349'], 
  [4, '#3eb060']
].map((d, i) => ({
  index: i, 
  color: d[1],
  k: d[0]
}));

let arc = d3.arc().cornerRadius(10).startAngle(0);
let svg = d3.select('svg');
let size = Math.PI*3/2;
arcs(true);
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(dt) {
  arcs(false, dt);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function arcs(isBg, dt) {
  let selection = svg.selectAll('path.'+ (isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc'))
  selection = selection.data(data).enter().append('path').merge(selection);
  selection.classed(isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc', true)
    .attr('fill', d => isBg ? '#ccc' : d.color)
    .attr('d', d => arc({
      innerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + (d.index?0:3),
      outerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + 8,
      endAngle: isBg ? size : (d.k*dt/300%100)*size/100
    }))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
  <svg viewBox="-75 -75 150 150" height="100vh"></svg>
<body>
```

---

Вариант, в котором видно как инициализировать диаграмму внешними данными

```js
chart([ 
  [20, '#0578e9', "142 000 м²"], 
  [40, '#f278bb', "82 000 м²"], 
  [60, '#f9b349', "60 000 м²"], 
  [80, '#3eb060', "20 000 м²"]
].map((d, i) => ({
  index: i, 
  color: d[1],
  value: d[0],
  text: d[2]
})));

function chart(data){
  let arc = d3.arc().cornerRadius(10).startAngle(0);
  let svg = d3.select('svg');
  let size = Math.PI*3/2;
  arcs(true);
  arcs(false);
  svg.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text')
     .text( d => d.text)
     .style('font-size', 10)
     .style('text-anchor', 'end')
     .style('font-family', 'arial')
     .attr('x', -10)
     .attr('y', d => d.index*14-65)

  function arcs(isBg) {
    let selection = svg.selectAll('path.'+ (isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc'))
    selection = selection.data(data).enter().append('path').merge(selection);
    selection.classed(isBg ? 'bg' : 'arc', true)
      .attr('fill', d => isBg ? '#ccc' : d.color)
      .attr('d', d => arc({
        innerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + (d.index?0:3),
        outerRadius: 20 + d.index*15 + 8,
        endAngle: isBg ? size : d.value*size/100
      }))
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
  <svg viewBox="-75 -75 150 150" height="100vh"></svg>
<body>
```

Comment: за D3 плюсик поставил ...

Comment: @MaximLensky благодарствую, предпочитаю при помощи нее рисовать, по мне это проще чем в svg редакторе =)

Comment: в любом редакторе SVG куча ограничений ...на том же js или d3 эти ограничения легко обходятся

Comment: А как мене вставлять значения в этот график, чтобы можно было рисовать дуги определенной длины?

Comment: Желательно динамически. Но можно и проще. Нужно иметь возможность туда вставлять любые значения. Там я дописал вопрос с картинкой. Это что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Идеально подошло.

Comment: @Denis обращайтесь

Comment: @Denis вот такой еще недавно делал =) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962939/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/962996#962996