# как исправить этот код параллакса?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

```js
var $layer_0 = $('.layer-0'),
  $layer_1 = $('.layer-1'),
  $layer_2 = $('.layer-2'),
  $x_axis = $('#x-axis'),
  $y_axis = $('#y-axis'),
  $container = $('body'),
  container_w = $container.width(),
  container_h = $container.height();

$(window).on('mousemove.parallax', function(event) {
  var pos_x = event.pageX,
    pos_y = event.pageY,
    left = 0,
    top = 0;

  left = container_w / 2 - pos_x;
  top = container_h / 2 - pos_y;

  TweenMax.to(
    $x_axis,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + (left * -1) + 'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $y_axis,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateY(' + (top * -1) + 'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_2,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + left / 12 + 'px) translateY(' + top / 6 +
          'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_1,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + left / 4 + 'px) translateY(' + top / 2 +
          'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_0,
    10, {
      css: {
        transform: 'rotate(' + left / 200 + 'deg)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'none'
    }
  )
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #010c0d;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.axis {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.planet {
  background-size: cover;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#background {
  background-image: url("http://www.alienresearchcorp.com/space/hd- 
 wallpapers/amazing/img/l/moment-in-space-cvi.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: -20%;
  left: -10%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: -20%;
}

#x-axis {
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 1px;
}

#y-axis {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

#planet-1 {
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: url("http://th02.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2012/337/3/6/
 planet_png_by_phip_phantom-d5mwylq.png");
 z-index: 20;
}

#planet-2 {
  margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/070/e/d/
 ice_planet___kronos_by_khrymsyn-d5xqmnm.png");
 z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="layer-0"></div>
<div id="x-axis" class="axis"></div>
<div id="y-axis" class="axis"></div>
<div id="planet-1" class="planet layer-1"></div>
<div id="planet-2" class="planet layer-2"></div>
```

Comment: А где простите у вас объявление переменной `TweenMax` ну или скажем подгрузка плагина?

Answer (score 5):

У вас в `css` сломаны ссылки на изображения, это произошло скорее всего из-за `ctrl+c` `ctrl+v` плюс одна оказалась протухшая...

в ссылках на изображения лишний перевод на новую строку, его необходимо убрать:

```js
var $layer_0 = $('.layer-0'),
  $layer_1 = $('.layer-1'),
  $layer_2 = $('.layer-2'),
  $x_axis = $('#x-axis'),
  $y_axis = $('#y-axis'),
  $container = $('body')


$(window).on('mousemove.parallax', function(event) {
  var container_w = $container.width(),
    container_h = $container.height(), 
    pos_x = event.pageX,
    pos_y = event.pageY,
    left = 0,
    top = 0;

  left = container_w / 2 - pos_x;
  top = container_h / 2 - pos_y;

  TweenMax.to(
    $x_axis,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + (left * -1) + 'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $y_axis,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateY(' + (top * -1) + 'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_2,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + left / 12 + 'px) translateY(' + top / 6 +
          'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_1,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + left / 4 + 'px) translateY(' + top / 2 +
          'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_0,
    10, {
      css: {
        transform: 'rotate(' + left / 200 + 'deg)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'none'
    }
  )
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #010c0d;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.axis {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.planet {
  background-size: cover;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#background {
  background-image: url("http://planetary-science.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/moment-in-space-cvi.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: -20%;
  left: -10%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: -20%;
}

#x-axis {
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 1px;
}

#y-axis {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

#planet-1 {
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: url("http://th02.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2012/337/3/6/planet_png_by_phip_phantom-d5mwylq.png");
 z-index: 20;
}

#planet-2 {
  margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/070/e/d/ice_planet___kronos_by_khrymsyn-d5xqmnm.png");
 z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="background" class="layer-0"></div>
<div id="x-axis" class="axis"></div>
<div id="y-axis" class="axis"></div>
<div id="planet-1" class="planet layer-1"></div>
<div id="planet-2" class="planet layer-2"></div>
```

PS: еще пришлось подключить [`greensock`](https://greensock.com/), хочу заметить это супер избыточно для такого примера

Comment: эффект божественный мне оч. понравилось.Держи плюс ).И кстати TweenMax отличная штука если что ;)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов я обычно пользуюсь этим https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

Comment: то есть вместо TweenMax этим пользуешься?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов так точно, функции сглаживания, это более гибко, особенно когда функцию от времени нужно сделать, а не просто сказать откуда и куда проехать

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов https://github.com/pshrmn/notes/blob/master/d3/interpolators.md вот это еще

Comment: хмм интересно..А зачем интерполяторы ?Тоже самое ?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов считать промежуточные состояния при анимациях

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. Очень интересно.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов вот тут интерполяторы в действии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962939/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/962996#962996

Comment: Разворачивание сниппета на весь экран работает криво.

Comment: @Qwertiy это прескорбно =) исправил

Comment: Ага, интересненько. Фон тоже движется)

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, крутится слегка

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял у вас просто не работает код, так вот, в этом примере всё работает, вам лишь нужно поменять фон, планету №1 и планету №2, также по желанию (возможности) изменить скрипт руководствуясь документацией на [официальном сайте проекта](https://greensock.com/docs/TweenMax).

```js
var $layer_0 = $('.layer-0'),
  $layer_1 = $('.layer-1'),
  $layer_2 = $('.layer-2'),
  $x_axis = $('#x-axis'),
  $y_axis = $('#y-axis'),
  $container = $('body'),
  container_w = $container.width(),
  container_h = $container.height();

$(window).on('mousemove.parallax', function(event) {
  var pos_x = event.pageX,
    pos_y = event.pageY,
    left = 0,
    top = 0;

  left = container_w / 2 - pos_x;
  top = container_h / 2 - pos_y;

  TweenMax.to(
    $x_axis,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + (left * -1) + 'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $y_axis,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateY(' + (top * -1) + 'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_2,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + left / 12 + 'px) translateY(' + top / 6 +
          'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_1,
    1, {
      css: {
        transform: 'translateX(' + left / 4 + 'px) translateY(' + top / 2 +
          'px)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'all'
    });

  TweenMax.to(
    $layer_0,
    10, {
      css: {
        transform: 'rotate(' + left / 200 + 'deg)'
      },
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      overwrite: 'none'
    }
  )
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #010c0d;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.axis {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.planet {
  background-size: cover;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#background {
  /* Картинку фона */
  background-image: url("https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1280x800/4/8c/peyzazh-nebo-goluboe-solnce.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: -20%;
  left: -10%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: -20%;
}

#x-axis {
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 1px;
}

#y-axis {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

#planet-1 {
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  /* Картинку планеты №1 */
  background-image: url("https://purepng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/purepng.com-earthearthplanetglobethird-planet-from-the-sun-1411526987783s16t2.png");
 z-index: 20;
}

#planet-2 {
  margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  /* Картинку планеты №2 */
  background-image: url("https://purepng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/purepng.com-earthearthplanetglobethird-planet-from-the-sun-1411526987783s16t2.png");
 z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Нужно вставить скрипт и поменять 3 изображения, фона, планеты №1, планеты №2 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div id="background" class="layer-0"></div>
<div id="x-axis" class="axis"></div>
<div id="y-axis" class="axis"></div>
<div id="planet-1" class="planet layer-1"></div>
<div id="planet-2" class="planet layer-2"></div>
```

Comment: При разволрачивании сниппета на всю страницу сбивается мышь.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ошибку надо подключить библиотеки!
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.7/TweenMax.min.js
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: только почему такая старая версия gsap? :)