# Как сверстать такой график?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, плагин

подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать такой круг? Требуется сделать такой график. Проблема в том что надо удобно менять значения?
Посоветуйте пожалуйста какой ни будь плагин

[image: Фото]

Comment: рисуйте все на `svg`

Comment: Такое можно сделать с помощью плагина D3.js [Пример](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/donut_label.html)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962996/188366

Comment: это актуально, или Вам хватило оешения по ссылке? )