# Кольцевая диаграмма на Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

**Тип диаграммы**: кольцевая.

**Особенность**: в зависимости от процентов меняется цвет диаграммы и ее заполнение соответственно.

**Характеристики**: меньше 30% - красный, от 31 до 75 - желтый, от 76 до 100 - зеленый.

**Визуальный пример**:

[image: кольцевая диаграмма]

Разметка в основном компоненте:

```
<div class="medicine-medical">
  <div class="medicine-medical_transform transform">
    <div class="notransform">
      <span>Медосмотр</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medicine-medical_block">
    <chart :userMedicalMedical="+worker.medinspection"/>
      <div class="img" ref="imgMedical"></div>
      <div class="data" ref="dataMedical"><p>{{worker.medinspection}} дн.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код из компонента с диаграммой:

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-window">
    <svg width='60px' height='60px'>
      <circle cx='25' cy='25' r='41%' fill='transparent' stroke-width='1'></circle>
      <circle cx='25' cy='25' r='37%' fill='transparent' stroke-width='5'></circle>
      <circle ref="diagrammMin" cx='25' cy='25' r='35%' fill='transparent' stroke-width='5'></circle>
      <circle ref="diagramm" cx='25' cy='25' r='35%' fill='transparent' stroke-width='5'></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "employeeCardChart",
    props: {
      userMedicalMedical: Number,
      percent: Number,
      userMedicalReplacement: Array,
      training: Object,
      worker: Object
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        warning: false,
        danger: false,
        flor: false,
        perpetual: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      /***
       * функция checkData - проверяет наличие полей и в дальнейшем, если  есть, тогда изменяет стили диаграммы
       * Выходные параметры :
       *  this.warning,this.danger,this,flor - ячейки дял хранения булевых значений -
       *    в дальнейшем нужны для определения приоритета оповещения
       *  diagramm - переменная содержащая в себе атрибут refs диаграммы ( участок, который изменяется от данных -
       *    цвет и положение )
       *
       */
   checkData() {
        // если есть this.userMedicalMedical - МЕДОСМОТР
        if (this.userMedicalMedical) {
          let diagrammMin = this.$refs.diagrammMin;
          let diagramm = this.$refs.diagramm;
          if (this.userMedicalMedical >= 30) {
            diagramm.style.strokeDasharray = '132 131';
            diagramm.style.stroke = 'rgba(50, 50, 60, 1)'
          } else if (this.userMedicalMedical <= 29 && this.userMedicalMedical >= 21) {
            diagrammMin.style.stroke = 'rgba(239, 127, 26, 1';                        // для внутреннего бордера
            diagramm.style.stroke = 'rgb(230, 230, 230)';                           //для внешнего бордера
            diagramm.style.strokeDasharray = '78 41';                             // положение внешнего бордера
            this.$refs.diagrammMin.style.strokeDasharray = '38 41.5';
          } else if (this.userMedicalMedical <= 20 && this.userMedicalMedical >= 14) {
            diagrammMin.style.stroke = 'rgba(239, 127, 26, 1';                        // для внутреннего бордера
            diagramm.style.stroke = 'rgb(230, 230, 230)';                           //для внешнего бордера
            this.$refs.diagrammMin.style.strokeDasharray = '63 3.8';
            diagramm.style.strokeDasharray = '65 67';
          } else if (this.userMedicalMedical <= 13 && this.userMedicalMedical >= 7) {
            diagrammMin.style.stroke = 'rgba(239, 127, 26, 1';                        // для внутреннего бордера
            diagramm.style.stroke = 'rgb(230, 230, 230)';                           //для внешнего бордера
            this.$refs.diagrammMin.style.strokeDasharray = '30, 3.3';
            diagramm.style.strokeDasharray = '30 102';
          } else {
            diagramm.style.stroke = 'rgba(181, 90, 110, 1)';                        //для внешнего бордера
          }
        }
        if (this.percent) {
          console.log(this.percent, '-------');
          let breathalyzerUp = this.percent * 1.32;
          let breathalyzerOn = this.$refs.diagramm;
          // x.style.strokeDasharray = `${y} 131`
          breathalyzerOn.style.strokeDasharray = `${breathalyzerUp} 131`
        }
                mounted() {
      this.checkData();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: нет на js не реализована в полной мере...(т.е есть что-то похожее но не рабочее...). Данные с БД приходят, но не получаеться настроить отображение(цвет не хочет меняться и заполнение всегда на 100%)

Comment: Уточняю... есть 2 компонента: 1 основной, а другой с диаграммой... подскажите какой кусок Вас интересует?

Comment: `'rgba(239, 127, 26, 1'` - здесь у вас опечатка. И не только там.

Comment: да проблема в отрисовке...

Comment: опечатки поправил...(странно что storm не подчеркнул...)

Comment: в `mounted` код выполнится только после готовности всех компонентов один раз и не факт что в этот момент данные уже пришли с сервера, поэтому его надо переместить (метод) в `computed` и тогда по изменении данных из вне страница перерендерится

Comment: исправил, но не сработало...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962996/188366

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/868598/256824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Упрощенный вариант, когда все стили для диаграммы находятся в вычисляемом свойстве, т.е. в поле `computed`. Это позволит вам самостоятельно решать, какие атрибуты вынести в разметку, а какие атрибуты должны зависеть от входных параметров `props`. Демо:

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

// Компонент круговой диаграммы.
const Chart = {
  // Имя компонента.
  name: 'chart',
  // Свойства, передаваемые от родительского компонента.
  props: {
    medinspection: Number
  },
  // Вычисляемые свойства.
  computed: {
    // Процент заполненности диаграммы, но без знака %.
    percent() {
      return this.$props.medinspection;
    },
    // Стили для диаграммы.
    diagramStyle() {
      // Определим локально для удобства.
      const percent = this.percent;

      // Примем длину окружности за константу.
      const length = 100;

      // Примем радиус окружности за константу.
      const radius = length / (Math.PI * 2)

      // Штрих - заполненная часть окружности.
      const dash = percent;

      // Промежуток - соответственно, не заполненная.
      const space = length - dash;

      // Цвет линии по умолчанию.
      let stroke = 'rgb(255, 121, 121)';

      if (percent > 75) {
        stroke = 'rgb(178, 214, 60)';
      } else if (percent > 30) {
        stroke = 'rgb(241, 196, 15)'
      }

      return {
        'cx': 21, // координата центра окружности по оси абсцисс
        'cy': 21, // координата центра окружности по оси ординат
        'r': radius, // радиус окружности или просто: 15.91549431
        'fill': 'none', // заливка элемента
        'stroke': stroke, // цвет линии
        'stroke-width': 6, // толщина линии
        'stroke-dasharray': `${dash} ${space}`, // штрих и промежуток
        'stroke-dashoffset': 0 // смещение пунктирной обводки
      }
    }
  },
  // Шаблон компонента.
  template: `<div class="chart__window">
      <!--
          viewBox - список из четырех чисел min-x, min-y, width и height,
          которые определяют прямоугольник в пользовательском пространстве.
          Должны быть удвоенными cx & cy и больше диаметра круга.
      -->
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42">
        <circle v-bind="diagramStyle"></circle>
      </svg>
      <span class="circle__percent">{{ percent }}%</span>
    </div>`,
}

// Создаем экземпляр приложения.
new Vue({
  // Корневой элемент, определяется по css селектору.
  el: '#app',
  // Локальная регистрация компонентов.
  components: {
    'chart': Chart
  },
  // Исходные данные. Модели.
  data: {
    worker: {
      medinspection: 10
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart__window {
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle__percent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <chart :medinspection="worker.medinspection"></chart>
  <input type="range" v-model.number="worker.medinspection" min="0" max="100" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

**Кольцевая диаграмма с анимацией**

Данный вариант посложнее, но принцип построения схож с первым: выносим значения атрибутов в `computed` поле. Демо:

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

// Компонент круговой диаграммы.
const CircleChart = {
  // Имя компонента.
  name: 'circle-chart',
  // Свойства, передаваемые от родительского компонента.
  props: {
    // Процент заполненности диаграммы, но без знака %.
    percent: Number,
    name: String
  },
  // Вычисляемые свойства.
  computed: {
    completed() {
      if (100 === this.percent) {
        return 'Full';
      } else if (!this.percent) {
        return 'O_o';
      }

      return this.percent + '%';
    },
    // Стили для диаграммы.
    diagramStyle() {
      // Определим локально для удобства.
      const percent = this.percent;

      // Примем длину окружности за константу.
      const length = 100;

      // Примем радиус окружности за константу.
      const radius = length / (Math.PI * 2);

      // Штрих - заполненная часть окружности.
      const dash = percent;

      // Промежуток - соответственно, не заполненная часть.
      const space = length - dash;

      // Цвет линии по умолчанию.
      let stroke = 'rgb(79, 83, 87)';

      return {
        'cx': 21, // координата центра окружности по оси асбцисс
        'cy': 21, // координата центра окружности по оси ординат
        'r': radius, // радиус окружности или просто: 15.91549431
        'fill': 'none', // заливка элемента
        'stroke': stroke, // цвет линии
        'stroke-width': .5, // толщина линии
        'stroke-linecap': 'round', // форма кончика линии
        'stroke-dasharray': `${dash} ${space}`, // штрих и промежуток

        // Смещение для начальной точки линии - штриха.
        // Смещение высчитывается против часовой стрелки.
        // При нуле будет начинаться с 3-х часов.
        // Нам нужно, чтобы начало линии было на 12-ть часов.
        // Значит, смещаем на 1/4 длины окружности: 100/4 = 25.
        // `transform: rotate` теперь можем не использовать.
        'stroke-dashoffset': 25,
      }
    },
    // Стили для фоновой окружности.
    // Унаследуем стили от наложенной диаграммы.
    backgroundStyle() {
      return {
        ...this.diagramStyle,
        'stroke': 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
        'stroke-width': .35,
        'stroke-dasharray': '100 0', // полный штрих, на весь круг
      }
    },
    animateDiagramStyle() {
      // Определим локально для удобства имя атрибута,
      // к которому будет применяться анимация.
      const attribute = 'stroke-dasharray';

      // Значения `from` & `to` переставляются местами,
      // когда нужен `reverse` анимации.
      return {
        'attributeName': attribute,
        'from': '0 100',
        'to': this.diagramStyle[attribute],
        'dur': '2s',
        'begin': '0',
        'fill': 'freeze',
      }
    }
  },
  // Шаблон компонента. `:key` задан только для демки,
  // для перерисовки компонента и
  // применения стилей анимации при изменении значений.
  template: `<div class="chart__window" :key="_uid + percent">
    <!--
      viewBox - список из четырех чисел min-x, min-y, width и height,
      которые определяют прямоугольник в пользовательском пространстве.
      Должны быть удвоенными cx & cy и больше диаметра круга.
    -->

    <svg class="circle-container" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle v-bind="backgroundStyle" />
      <circle v-bind="diagramStyle">
        <animate v-bind="animateDiagramStyle" />
      </circle>

      <g class="circle-chart-info">
        <text class="circle-chart-percent" x="21" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="8">{{ completed }}</text>
        <text class="circle-chart-subline" x="21" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2">{{ name }}</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>`,
}

// Создаем экземпляр приложения.
new Vue({
  // Корневой элемент, определяется по css селектору.
  el: '#app',
  // Локальная регистрация компонентов.
  components: {
    'circle-chart': CircleChart
  },
  // Исходные данные. Модели.
  data: {
    // Массив кольцевых диаграмм.
    charts: [{
      percent: 18,
      name: 'Первая'
    }, {
      percent: 64,
      name: 'Другая'
    }, {
      percent: 100,
      name: 'Еще одна'
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.chart__window {
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}



/**
 * С текстом не разбирался.
 */
.circle-chart-info {
  animation: circle-chart-appear 2s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0.3em);
}

@keyframes circle-chart-appear {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <template v-for="item in charts">
      <div class="chart__window">
        <input type="range" v-model.number="item.percent" min="0" max="100" />
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <template v-for="item in charts">
      <circle-chart v-bind="item"></circle-chart>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

**NB** К сожалению в svg я полный ноль.

Comment: Никогда не поздно начать изучать svg :-) По началу будет трудно, но всегда будет легче разобраться, зная основы SVG, почему фреймворки JS иногда, по непонятным причинам работают не так, как ожидалось.  Посмотрите топик, если есть желание как работать с dasharray svg [Помогите с dasharray и dashoffset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748)