# Polygon и path (Svg паттерны)

Tags: html, svg

В чем отличие **path** от **polygon**?

Какой из них желательно применять в svg паттернах.

**Пример:**

```html
<div class="path">
<svg width="350" height="200">

<path d="M0,100 100,100 80,80 20,80 20,20 0,0z" 
stroke="orange" stroke-width="2" fill="black"
transform="translate(65,20)"/>

</svg>
</div>
 



<div class="polygon">
<svg width="350" height="200">

<polygon points="0,100 100,100 80,80 20,80 20,20 0,0" 
stroke="orange" stroke-width="2" fill="gray"
transform="translate(65,20)"/>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: без разницы что применять

Comment: path удобнее ..

Comment: А какая между ними разница?

Comment: да нету разницы ...ну вообще polygon это многоугольник а path это просто любая фигура ..даже не знаю как объяснить

Comment: path проще на много ..

Comment: А есть статья где можно подробно прочитать про координаты которыми создаешь линии в polygon или path.  Долго искал так и не нашел. Везде льют только воду никакой конкретики((

Comment: @Black_Viper path сложнее и универсальнее, им можно нарисовать любую другую фигуру

Comment: polygon это частный случай path. В теории polygon, circle и т.п. проще писать если вы пишете svg вручную.

Comment: То есть при помощи polygon я могу нарисовать все что угодно и даже овал? Если да, то приведите пожалуйста пример овала)))

Comment: @Black_Viper нет, не можете. Наоборот, с помощью path можете нарисовать и круг и овал и полигон

Comment: Polygon это прямые линии?

Comment: Приехали… а в документации посмотреть? Или, хотя бы, в википедии

Comment: Просто хотел уточнить для уверенности))) Так это прямые да)?

Answer (score 2):

Вот смотрите, верхние фигуры я нарисовал разными примитивами а нижние при помощи `path`, кроме этого `path` позволяет рисовать еще много чего, за счет команд атрибута `d` :

Перемещение: `M, m`

Линия: `L, l, H, h, V, v`

Кубическая кривая Безье: `C, c, S, s`

Квадратичная кривая Безье: `Q, q, T, t`

Дуга: `A, a`

Закрыть путь: `Z, z`

Команды с большой буквы используют абсолютное позиционирование точек, а с маленькой - абсолютное относительно предыдущей точки пути

Подробнее что да как работает в пути [можно узнать вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)

```html
<svg fill="none" stroke="black" viewbox="0 0 250 100" height="100vh">

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="20"></rect>
  <path d="M10,10 h30 v 20 h-30 z"></path>
  
  <rect x="50" y="10" width="30" height="20" rx="5"></rect>
  <path d="M50,15a5,5,0,0,1,5,-5h20a5,5,0,0,1,5,5v10a5,5,0,0,1,-5,5h-20a5,5,0,0,1,-5-5z"></path>
  
  <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="10"></circle>
  <path d="M90,20a10,10,0,1,1,0,0.0001z"></path>
  
  <ellipse cx="135" cy="20" rx="15" ry="10"></ellipse>
  <path d="M120,20a15,10 0 1,0 30,0a15,10 0 1,0 -30,0"></path>
  
  <polygon points="160 10 180 30 155 15 180 20"></polygon>
  <path d="M160 10L180 30L155 15 L180 20 z"></path>
  
  <polyline points="190 10 210 30 185 15 210 20"></polyline>
  <path d="M190 10L210 30L185 15 L210 20 "></path>
  
  <line x1="220" y1="10" x2="240" y2="30"></line>
  <path d="M220 10 L240 30"></path>
  
  <style>
    path {
      transform:translate(0, 40px);
    }
  </style>
<svg>
```

Comment: В некоторых случаях координаты примитивов короче чем у path.

Comment: И все же результат один и тот же. Получается разницы нет?

Comment: А мне человек сверху написал, что при помощи path можно рисовать polygon. Это правильно)?

Comment: Так я и не спал. Благодарствую за просветление)) А где можно подробно прочитать про координаты при помощи которых рисуешь разные фигуры.

Answer (score 2):

Вот маленький пример того что можно не имея навыков программирования и не зная ни какой ЯП сделать вот такую ничтожную анимацию использую только(!) SVG

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="lg">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="gold"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="teal"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <g>
      <path d="M0,0 20,0 20,10 0,10z" fill="url(#lg)" opacity="0">
        <animate 
                 id="linear"
                 attributeName="opacity"
                 from="0" to="1"
                 dur="0.34s" 
                 begin="end.end" 
                 fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
      </path>
    </g>
   <g>
     <text style="font-size: 1.5px; font-weight:900;" x="4.5" y="-1">
       Hello
        <animate 
          id="text"
          attributeName="y"
          from="-1"
          to="4"
          repeatCount="1"
          dur="1s"
          begin="shape.end"
          fill="freeze"  />  
        <animate 
          id="t1"
          attributeName="fill"
          from="#000"
          to="#fff"
          repeatCount="1"
          dur="1s"
          begin="linear.end"
          fill="freeze"  />  
     </text>   
  </g>
  
     <g>
     <text style="font-size: 1.5px; font-weight:900;" x="30" y="4">
       Everybody
        <animate 
          id="end"
          attributeName="x"
          from="30"
          to="8.5"
          repeatCount="1"
          dur="1s"
          begin="text.end"
          fill="freeze"  /> 
          <animate 
          id=""
          attributeName="fill"
          from="#000"
          to="#fff"
          repeatCount="1"
          dur="1s"
          begin="t1.end"
          fill="freeze"  /> 
     </text>   
  </g>
  
  <g style="display: ;">
    <path d="M0,0  20,0  20,10  0,10  0,0z" fill="lightgreen" stroke="none">
      <animate 
        id="shape"
        attributeName="d"
        values="M0,0  3,0  20,10  0,10  0,0z;
                M0,0  3,7.5  20,10  0,10  0,0z"
        repeatCount="1"
        dur="1s"
        begin="btn.click"
        fill="freeze"    
      />
    </path>
  </g>
  
  <g style="cursor: pointer;" id="btn">
   <rect width="3" height="1.5" x="8" y="7" fill="lightblue" rx="0.2" />
    <text style="user-select: none; font-size:0.8px; fill:#fff;" x="8.5" y="8"> button</text>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/999998/188366

Comment: Яп - это язык программирования?
Просто я не силен в сленгах)))
А обычно на каких языках программирования пишут анимации?

Answer (score 1):

К примеру и на polygon тоже можно нарисовать круг, но для этого надо пользоваться генераторами типа Illustrator, Corel Draw как и я в этом случае

Но надо не забывать что эти редакторы прежде всего решения для дизайнеров и пользоваться надо ими с умом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div style="width:400px; margin:auto;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30000 30000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g >
  <polygon fill="none" stroke-width="100px" stroke="red" points="15355.6,2418.53 14297.52,2501.44 13239.42,2584.35 12210.18,2830.83 11180.96,3077.31 10208.65,3480.61 9236.36,3883.93 8347.52,4433.09 7458.69,4982.24 6677.55,5662.24 5896.42,6342.26 5244.3,7134.58 4592.18,7926.9 4086.85,8809.93 3581.53,9692.94 3236.79,10642.57 2892.05,11592.21 2717.3,12582.54 2542.54,13572.88 2542.54,14576.92 2542.54,15580.94 2717.29,16571.28 2892.05,17561.62 3236.79,18511.25 3581.53,19460.88 4086.85,20343.9 4592.18,21226.91 5244.29,22019.24 5896.41,22811.56 6677.55,23491.57 7458.68,24171.59 8347.52,24720.75 9236.35,25269.9 10208.65,25673.2 11180.94,26076.52 12210.17,26323 13239.41,26569.48 14297.5,26652.39 15355.6,26735.3 16413.68,26652.39 17471.78,26569.48 18501.02,26323 19530.24,26076.52 20502.55,25673.22 21474.84,25269.9 22363.68,24720.75 23252.51,24171.59 24033.65,23491.59 24814.78,22811.57 25466.9,22019.25 26119.02,21226.93 26624.35,20343.9 27129.67,19460.89 27474.41,18511.26 27819.15,17561.62 27993.9,16571.29 28168.66,15580.95 28168.66,14576.92 28168.66,13572.89 27993.91,12582.55 27819.15,11592.21 27474.41,10642.58 27129.67,9692.95 26624.35,8809.93 26119.02,7926.92 25466.91,7134.59 24814.79,6342.27 24033.65,5662.26 23252.53,4982.24 22363.68,4433.09 21474.85,3883.93 20502.55,3480.63 19530.26,3077.31 18501.03,2830.83 17471.79,2584.35 16413.7,2501.44 "/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: еще js можно воспользоваться чтобы точки посчитать =)

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/qzLONR

Comment: я поэтому и говорю что редактор часто не нужен, иногда проще из головы посчитать или по формуле, с кривыми Безье посложнее формула, а принцип тот же

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001237/308951

Answer (score 1):

```css
svg{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewbox="0 0 5 5"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <defs>
       <clipPath id="clip">
          <path d="M0.1,1.5  2.5,0.1  4.9,1.5  4.9,3.5  2.5,4.9  0.1,3.5z" />
       </clipPath>
    </defs>
  <g>
   <path d="M0.1,1.5  2.5,0.1  4.9,1.5  4.9,3.5  2.5,4.9  0.1,3.5z" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="0.2" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
   <image xlink:href="https://pp.userapi.com/c637222/v637222085/2aa06/2hO_8t4jw0A.jpg" width="4.9" height="4.9" x="0.1" y="0.1" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
  </g>
</svg>

<hr>

<svg width="300" height="300" viewbox="0 0 5 5"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <defs>
       <clipPath id="clip1">
         <path d="M0.1,4.9 4.9,4.9 2.5,0.1z" />
       </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0.1,4.9  4.9,4.9  2.5,0.1z" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="0.2" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
     <image xlink:href="https://pp.userapi.com/c637222/v637222085/2aa06/2hO_8t4jw0A.jpg" width="4.9" height="4.9" x="0.1" y="0.1" clip-path="url(#clip1)" />
</svg>
```